# Git undo uncommitted changes to several files (but not all) with one command and with untracked files mixed in

Tags: git

Say I had a repo structure with the following unstaged changes:

```
modified: A/B/C/file1
modified: A/B/C/D/file2
modified: A/B/E/file3
```

How would I revert changes from only file1 and file2 with a single command? The command `git checkout -- A/B/C/*` doesn't work because A/B/C also contains several generated files which aren't versioned. The error from git is "error: pathspec 'A/B/C/file4' did not match any file(s) known to git"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The command `git checkout -- A/B/C/*` doesn't work because `A/B/C` also contains several generated files which aren't versioned.

That's because you're letting your shell do the glob expansion, so it's looking at all files.

If you instead let `git` to do its own glob expansion, it will only look at files already under version control:

```bash
$ git checkout -- A/B/C/\*
```

Although frankly I'd prefer to run two commands than to worry about manually deciding which special characters are handled where.

Comment: If I could separately upvote the "I'd prefer to run two commands than to worry about manually deciding which special characters are handled where" part, I'd give that about 10 upvotes. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I figured I could do the shell glob because git diff A/B/C/* > patchfile.patch works as expected. The reason I can't run two commands is that my actual use case has about a dozen files I want to undo, I just simplified it to illustrate my problem.